# Python multiprocessing program possible deadlock?

Tags: python, deadlock

Could some explain to me why this hangs sometimes? (This is just for learning purposes, I wouldn't sum a list like that)

```
import multiprocessing as mp
q = mp.JoinableQueue()

def worker():
  S = 0
  while not q.empty():
    S += q.get()
    q.task_done()
  print(S)


procs = []


for i in range(1000):
  q.put(i)

for i in range(2):
    t = mp.Process(target=worker)
    t.start()
    procs.append(t)


q.join()

for t in procs:
    t.join()
```

Comment: Towards the end of the process, it's possible for `q.empty()` to return False, but the last item in the queue be retrieved by another thread before you can call `q.get()`, in which case it will hang forever.  You need to use `get_nowait()` instead, and catch the `Queue.Empty` exception as the indication that you're done.

Comment: @jasonharper Thank you very much!